# Opencv C++ code translation to Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am translating a script from `C++` to `Java` but experiencing a lot of issues the most common being `Mat.data[]`, I know it could be `Mat.get()` or `Mat.put()` in `Java` looking at the way its being used, but from the looks of things its not being treated like a matrix it is, here is the code I have translated up to the point where am stuck

```
int detectLane(Mat frame, Mat lines)
{
    int element_shape= Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,an=1;
    int thrs1=0,thrs2=4000;
    double rho=1,theta=Math.PI/180;
    Scalar color;
    int y,i,j;

    VMeanDist(frame,vmeandist);

    y=findHorizon(vmeandist);
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<canny.cols();j++)
        {
            //I cannot think of java implementation of this
            frame.data[ero.cols()*i+j]=0;             
        }
    }
```

and here is the original `C++` code

```
int detectLane(cv::Mat &frame,std::vector<cv::Vec4i>lines)
{
    int element_shape=cv::MORPH_RECT,an=1;
    int thrs1=0,thrs2=4000;
    double rho=1,theta=CV_PI/180;
    cv::Scalar color;
    int y,i,j;
    //cv::vector <cv::Vec2f> lines;
    //cv::vector <cv::Vec4i> lines;
    VMeanDist(frame,vmeandist);
    //std::cout<<vmeandist.data<<std::endl;
    y=findHorizon(vmeandist);
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<canny.cols;j++)
        {
            frame.data[ero.cols*i+j]=0;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance, and if you notice any mistakes in my translation please help correct it.

Comment: The C++ code sets the value of the array. It seems to me that the Java version will be straightforward: put().

Comment: if its put then what index is it exactly?

Comment: What it says in the code: ero.cols*i+j. Seems like a no-brainer to me.

Comment: Note that given row "i", column "j", if the matrix is treated like a row-major oriented array, the index of that cell is i*number_of_columns+j. Think about it.